# Is there a free-to-use EAN barcode scanning library for iOS without copyleft licensing?

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I'm looking for a library to scan EAN codes in iOS.  So far I've come across

- [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) but the iOS port scans only QR
- [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) which is copyleft licensed
- [Cocoa-Touch-Barcode](https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes) which only generates codes
- commercial libraries like [shopsavvy's scannerkit](http://shopsavvy.mobi/category/scannerkit-sdk/)

However what I need is a free-to-use library without the copyleft restrictions. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) port seems alive and updated to ZXing 2.0 !